# Gaps between overlapping letters

Tags: inkscape, fonts

I am using Inkscape 1.3. Trying to use the "Milkshake" font, I see weird gaps between the overlapping letters, as can be seen below:

[image]

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the Fill and Stroke Panel, select the Fill tab, and make sure you select the *Fill is Solid* option.

[image]

Here's the result

[image]

Comment: That solves it! thank you.